# Use mathematical induction to prove that $n^ 3 − n$ is divisible by 3 whenever n is a positive integer.

Tags: induction

Solution:  Let $P(n)$ be the proposition “$n^3−n$ is divisible by $3$ whenever $n$ is a positive integer”. Basis Step:The statement $P(1)$ is true because $1^3−1=0$ is divisible by $3$. This completes the basis step. Inductive Step:Assume that $P(k)$is true; i.e. $k^3−k$ is divisible by $3$. To complete the inductive step, we must show that when we assume the inductive hypothesis, it follows that $P(k+1)$, the statement that $(k+1)^3− (k+1)$ is divisible by $3$, is also true. That is,we must show that $(k+1)^3− (k+1)$ is divisible by $3$ . $(k+1)^3− (k+1)  =(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)-(k+1)$ this where I want to factorize ..need help.

Comment: If you want to factorise, you'd better do it this way: $(k+1)^3-(k+1)=(k+1)((k+1)^2-1)$.

Answer (score 6):

In the inductive step we assumed that $k^3 - k$ is divisible by 3 which means that $k^3 - k = 3M$ where $M$ is an integer. Now we can easily deduce $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$. 
\begin{align}
(k + 1)^3 - (k + 1) &= k^3 +3k^2 +3k +  1 -k - 1\\
&= (k^3- k) + 3k^2 + 3k\\
&= 3M +3k^2 + 3k\\
&= 3(M + k^2 + k)\\
&= 3Z
\end{align}
where $Z = M + k^2 + k$. Since $Z$ is an integer, it is clear $(k + 1)^3 - (k + 1)$ is divisible by 3 if $k^3 - k$ is divisible by 3. Thus concludes the proof.

Now there is a much easier proof that does not require induction, factor $n^3 - n$ as $n(n - 1)(n + 1) = (n - 1)n(n+1)$. Now $n - 1, n$ and $n+1$ are 3 consecutive integers, so one of them must be divisible by 3 since $n \text{ mod } 3$ can take on 3 different values(0, 1 and 2) and the 3 consecutive integers each have a different value, so one of them will be 0 (mod 3). Since one of the integers in the product is divisible by 3, so is the whole product.

Comment: Doesn't $(k+1)^3$ expand out to $k^3 + 3k^2 + 3\boldsymbol{k} +1$?

Comment: @jct Edited. THanks

Answer (score 1):

**BASE Step:-**

$n=1$

Then, $n^3-n=1^3-1=0$

And,$3|0$   (Basically any number has the capacity to divide $0$)

**ASSUMPTION Step:-**

Let us assume that for some Integer $k$, $(n=k)$
it holds *i.e.* $3|(k^3-k)$

**INDUCTIVE Step:-**

For the Inductive Step , We have to show the above proposition holds for $n=k+1$ 
 *i.e.*

$3|(k+1)^3-(k+1)$

So while simplifying We will apply a small trick which makes the problem easy to  understand

$(k+1)^3-(k+1)$

$=(k+1){(k+1)^2-1}$

$=(k+1){(k+1-1)(k+1+1)}$

$=(k+1){k(k+2)}$

$=k(k+1)(k+2)$

$=k(k+1)(k-1+3)$

$=(k-1)k(k+1)+3.k(k+1)$

$3|3.k(k+1)$

And by our assumption Step,

$3|(k-1)k(k+1)$

$\Rightarrow 3|k(k+1)(k-1)+3.k(k+1)$

$\Rightarrow 3|(k+1)^3-(k+1)$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$((n+1)^3-(n+1))-((n^3)-(n))$

$=3n+3n^2$

Comment: Difference between consecutive numbers is a multiple of 3.. show that first number is a multiple of 3

Answer (score 0):

We get $k^3+3k^2+2k=k(k+1)(k+2)$ because k is an integer and we have a multiplications of 3 sequential integers it is divisible by 3.

Note this does not use induction.