# Prove of the modular equation $(n^3 - n) (mod\;24) = 0$ with induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, induction

I need to prove this statement with induction:
if n is odd then $n^3 - n $ is divisible by 24

I've proved the base case (when $n = 1$) but I only have a small idea of what is to do in the induction step ($p(n) \Longrightarrow p(n+2)$)

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792506/use-mathematical-induction-to-prove-that-n-3-%E2%88%92-n-is-divisible-by-3-whenever-n) is another duplicate, that isn't restricted to even $n$.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot.

Comment: This is easy, $n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$, therefore:
1) 2|(n-1), 2|(n+1) thus $4|n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$
2) either 3|(n-1), 3|n or 3|(n+1)